# SQL Server - Backlog records

Tags: sql-server

My table ('Actions') structure & records are as below:

```
Action_ID   Open_date           Close_date
---------       -----------------------         -----------------------
ACT1001     2015-06-18 03:58:08.000     NULL
ACT1002     2015-06-28 06:01:10.000     2015-06-30 10:11:21.000
ACT1003     2015-07-08 01:40:19.000     2015-07-09 00:29:53.000
ACT1004     2015-07-09 04:32:00.000     NULL
ACT1005     2015-07-08 21:56:20.000     2015-07-09 01:12:37.000
ACT1006     2015-07-16 17:45:56.000     2015-08-15 23:24:35.000             
ACT1007     2015-08-05 17:54:25.000     NULL
ACT1008     2015-08-30 08:29:57.000     2015-08-30 22:11:45.000
ACT1009     2015-08-28 04:17:42.000     2015-09-11 21:39:11.000             
ACT1010     2015-09-16 07:00:01.000     2015-09-16 19:11:29.000
```

Based on the above 'Actions' table, I developed a matrix (counts) report as below:

```
YEAR    MONTH   BACKLOG OPENED_ACTIONS  CLOSED_ACTIONS  STILL_OPEN
----    -----   ------- --------------  --------------  ----------
2015    6   0   2       1       1
2015    7   1   4       2       3
2015    8   3   3       2       4
2015    9   4   1       2       3
```

Now, I am trying to find BACKLOG records for each & every month.
My results should be as below:

```
YEAR    MONTH   BACKLOG_ACTIONS
----    -----   ---------------
2015    6   NULL            
2015    7   ACT1002         
2015    8   ACT1002
2015    8   ACT1004
2015    8   ACT1006         
2015    9   ACT1002
2015    9   ACT1004
2015    9   ACT1007
2015    9   ACT1009
```

Can someone help me with writing the SQL for the above result using MS SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @rupa you should try to include in your question what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
1) Load the activity months to a cte. MONTHNUM codes for reporting over calender years
2) Join the open actions
note:- if there is no activity in a calender month the output will not  
produce anything for that month. 
If you have a dates table in your DB it might be better to use that as
the driver rather than ACTIONS.
 */

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT YEAR(OPEN_DATE) CCYY, MONTH(OPEN_DATE) MM,YEAR(OPEN_DATE) * 12 + MONTH(OPEN_DATE) MONTHNUM
FROM    ACTIONS
GROUP   BY yEAR(OPEN_DATE),MONTH(OPEN_DATE),YEAR(OPEN_DATE) * 12 + MONTH(OPEN_DATE)
)
SELECT   CCYY,MM,MONTHNUM,A.*
FROM    CTE  
LEFT JOIN   ACTIONS A ON YEAR(A.OPEN_DATE) * 12 + MONTH(A.OPEN_DATE) < MONTHNUM 
WHERE   A.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL
```